# Maintain scroll position after refresh of a web browser control in vb6

Tags: vb6

Is there any way to maintain a scroll position when you refresh a web control browser?

Comment: The question says vb6 but it is tagged vb.net

Comment: sorry bout that mate, I used only vb tag.

Comment: Can you please eloborate on what is meant by a web control browser? Are you referring to a VB6 IIS application or an ActiveX control being hosted in an IE browser?